# Bootstrap Collapse sometimes adds # to URL and sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

On the same page I have this code

`<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu1" aria-expanded="true">Menu Item with Sub-Items <b class="caret-blue"></b></a>`

and this code

`<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" class="">Collapsible Group Item #1</a>`

The first one adds `#` to the URL and moves the scrollbar to the top of the page. The second ones adds nothing to the URL and doesn't move the page. Both do the collapse function correctly.

WTF? Why do they act differently? I imagine Bootstrap is doing a `preventDefault()` on the event in one case and not the other, but why.

Per Bootstrap's documentation it's correct I think (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) but it's not acting like it should.

Comment: WTF? is the question?

Comment: Sorry, the question was why they were acting different.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `data-target="#menu1"` on the first link but `href="#menu1"` as the doc advises :

> You can use a link with the href attribute, or a button with the
>   data-target attribute. In both cases, the data-toggle="collapse" is
>   required.

Comment: After playing around I figured out the same thing but missed that in the docs. Thanks. Will accept in 5 mins when available.